# What are some really cool problems that involve "least squares and Eigenvalue problems"?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, numerical-methods, big-list

I am required to find a research topic in this domain, so I'm really interested in finding out what kind of problems are covered in this domain, and how others are using these techniques to solve them. Preferably, I'd be more interested in if/how one can use them in Machine Learning or Pattern Recognition.

I know this is a very open-ended questions, so I will not get a concrete answer. At this point, I only require a board answer to help me get started to get acquainted more with this area.

Comment: I've added a few relevant (meta-)tags. But I think there are quite a lot so you will surely find diverse answers. Least-Square problems are very interesting in approximation of boundary conditions for non-interpolatory bases in finite element methods, for example.
$$\min_{u^h \in \mathcal V} \|u - u^h\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)}$$
Where $\mathcal V$ is some finite-dimensional subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: might want to look into principle component analysis or independent component analysis

Comment: The entire subject of spectral graph theory falls into this question, and seems related to the applications you are interested in. Also PCA and similar.

Comment: Can you maybe find me a link where I can read more about this? I am really a newbie at this, and I am sure I can not find better result that you can.

Comment: Non-Negative Least Squares (NNLS) is used for various feature or object recognition problems. Example: Nhat Vo, Bill Moran, Subhash Challa, "Nonnegative-Least-Square Classifier for Face Recognition". In: ISNN 2009, Proceedings of the 6th International Symposium on Neural Networks: Advances in Neural Networks - Part III, pp. 449-456. *In this paper, we propose a novel classification method, based on Nonnegative-Least-Square (NNLS) algorithm, for face recognition*